# Looking for an algorithm to find the beginning and end of a set of data in the middle of an array of nulls

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Say I have an array of 5000 elements. Somewhere in the middle of the array, say from a[4200] through a[4300], is data. Values outside of this range return null.

What is the most efficient way to find the first and last entry containing data, **while querying the array as few times as possible**? Is there a name for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What do you know about this sequence of data ? For example : there is only one sequence of data, data can't be 0, the sequence of data has a size at least K - in this case test each K-1 numbers dans run back when you find the sequence - or at most M ? Do you have access to hardware acceleration components (some can do ORs of many datas, which can accelerate your problem) ?

Unclear statements such as the one you proposed will lead to generic solutions - like running through the whole array that anybody would think of...

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there are k non-null items in the middle of an array of length n, then you may need to make n/k checks before you find a data element, just by checking every kth one.  After that you can do a binary search to find the ends.

If you don't know k, then you can recursively divide the range into smaller and smaller regions, in breadth-first order, by checking the middle of each one.  This will still take O(n/k) checks in the worst case.  The binary searches to find the ends then take O(log k), for O(n/k + log k) all together.

Here it is in python:

```py
def findData(A):
    if (len(A)<1):
        return None
    q = [(0,len(A))]
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(q):
        (s,e) = q[pos]
        pos += 1
        mid = s + (e-s)//2
        if A[mid] == None:
            # Didn't find data. Subdivide range
            if mid > s:
                q.append((s,mid))
            if mid+1 < e:
                q.append((mid+1,e))
            continue

        # Found data
        maxs = mid # max start pos
        mine = mid+1 # min end pos

        # Binary search to find start
        while s < maxs:
            mid = s + (maxs-s)//2
            if A[mid] == None:
                s = mid+1
            else:
                maxs = mid
        
        # Binary search to find end
        while mine < e:
            mid = mine + (e-mine)//2
            if A[mid] == None:
                e = mid
            else:
                mine = mid+1
        
        return(s,e)
    
    # Searched the whole array and found no data
    return None
```

Test:

```
$> print(findData([
    None,None,None,1,2,3,4,5,None
]))
(3,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

- iterate through array using iterator j
- while data[j] = '\0', keep going
- condition breaks, set start = that position.
- another while, this time, while data[j] != '\0'
- once that breaks, set end = that position. minus one if you don't want it to be at a null.

You're done.

As for the "querying the array bit," I imagine it would be rather difficult to not do it this way, as the nulls could hypothetically end anywhere.

Comment: In my implementation, each query is expensive. I need to find the beginning and end in an intelligent and efficient manner. I'm looking for general algorithm advice, I'm not actually searching a small array of integers.